# Odoo 12: Input Required validation not working in portal template

Tags: xml, forms, validation, odoo-12

I'm trying to make a form in a portal template for odoo 12 and I want to make some of the inputs required.  Here is my dialog box for the form. Everything else with the form works as intended except for the required element in some of the inputs.

```
<div role="dialog" class="modal fade" id="wc-modal-new_line" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <header class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Item</h4>
              </header>
              <form method="post" t-attf-action="/my/equipment_requests/#{equipment_request.id}/new_line">
                <input class="d-none" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                <main class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <table border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td><label for="type">Loan Type </label></td>
                        <td>
                          <select name="type">
                            <option value="long">Long Term</option>
                            <option value="short">Short Term</option>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><label for="vendor_id">Vendor </label></td>
                        <td>
                          <select name="vendor_id">
                            <t t-foreach="vendors" t-as="vendor">
                              <option t-attf-value="#{vendor.id}"><span t-field="vendor.name"/></option>
                            </t>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label for="product_id">Product </label></td>
                        <td>
                          <select type="selection" name="product_id">
                            <t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
                              <option t-attf-value="#{product.id}"><span t-field="product.display_name"/></option>
                            </t>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><label for="name">Description * </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" required="required"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label for="product_qty">Quantity * </label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="product_qty" required="required"/></td>
                        <td><label for="price_unit">Unit Price *</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="price_unit" required="required"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label for="reason">Reason * </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="reason" required="required"/></td>
                        <td><label for="web_address">Web Address </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="web_address" placeholder="https://www.moddulu.com"/></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </main>
                <footer class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary contract-submit">Add Item</button>
                </footer>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried to `use required=""`, `required`, `use required="1"`, and `required="required"` and none of them work.  Any ideas would be helpful.  I have to do some type conversion on several of the fields and it's throwing an error if the fields aren't populated.

EDIT: I've also tried `data-is-required="true"` like in the payment acquirer forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>` into the frontend assets and added the following after the form to validate it.  After that it was simply adding some css to the .error class to change color and everything worked great!

```
<script>
   ("#addRequestLine").validate();
</script>
```